# This endpoint requires at least one of the following scopes: profile, surge_accept, request, request.delegate

Tags: oauth, uber-api

I am developing an application using Uber API, I used Retrofit library for retrieving data from API.

I have authorized my application using below endpoint:

```
https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/authorize?client_id=<CLIENT_ID>&response_type=code
```

But when I tried to get estimates of products using below endpoint:

```
https://api.uber.com/v1.2/requests/estimate?start_latitude=37.7752278&start_longitude=-122.4197513&end_latitude=37.7773228&end_longitude=-122.4272052
```

Then I got an issue:

> This endpoint requires at least one of the following scopes: profile, surge_accept, request.delegate.tos_accept, request, request.delegate","code":"unauthorized

Before implementing this endpoint I have completely done authorization & token  procedure by following Uber official doc.

Also I'm showing my source code below please let me know where I'm going wrong:

```
----> Intializing UBER SDK  <----

public void initializeUber() {
    if (!UberSdk.isInitialized()) {
        configuration = new SessionConfiguration.Builder().setClientId("LWOUTh3AUBkVtaI-cK58-t_pspsvRFfk").setServerToken("J5MNweewRs8vj4-dC0r9OMI4-qjibix0xv6gncGs").setRedirectUri("REDIRECT_URL").setScopes(Arrays.asList(Scope.REQUEST)).setEnvironment(SessionConfiguration.Environment.SANDBOX).build();

        UberSdk.initialize(configuration);

        accessTokenManager = new AccessTokenManager(context);
        System.out.println("Configuration-  ---->
            "+configuration.toString());
        loginManager = new LoginManager(accessTokenManager, new UberLoginCallback(context), configuration, LOGIN_CODE);
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "Uber SDK already initialized");
    }
}

public LoginManager getLoginManager() {
    PreferenceManager(context).setUberAuthToken(loginManager.getAccessTokenManager().getAccessToken().toString());
    System.out.println("Is authenticated-+loginManager.getAccessTokenManager().getAccessToken());
    return loginManager;
}

----->  Created API Interface  <----

@POST("v1.2/requests/estimate?")
Call<RequestEstimateFare> getRequestEstimateFare(@Query("start_latitude") String start_latitude, @Query("start_longitude") String start_longitude, @Query("end_latitude") String end_latitude, @Query("end_longitude") String end_longitude);

---->  Retrofit Library calling  <-----

apiInterface = retrofitConfig.createService(ApiInterface.class);
retrofitConfig.changeApiBaseUrl("https://api.uber.com/");
apiInterface.getRequestEstimateFare ("37.7752315", "-122.418075", "37.7752415", "-122.518075").enqueue(new Callback<RequestEstimateFare>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<RequestEstimateFare> call, Response<RequestEstimateFare> response) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<RequestEstimateFare> call, Throwable t) {
    }
});
```

I'm still getting the same issue.

Comment: Really hard to read the post without the correct code blocks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have not requested the 'request' scope during the oauth authorization process.

like:
`https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/authorize?client_id=<CLIENT_ID>&response_type=code&scope=request`

or if you want all scope then you need to pass all in link like:
`https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/authorize?client_id=<CLIENT_ID>&response_type=code&scope=request request_receipt history profile`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, are you making this request as one of your 5 approved developer accounts? or have you requested FULL ACCESS?

https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/requests-estimate-post

> Privileged Scope This endpoint requires a privileged scope to be used
>   in production by all Uber riders. You can use this endpoint
>   immediately when authenticated as yourself or any of your 5 registered
>   developers. When you are ready to distribute your application broadly
>   for use by all Uber riders, you may request FULL ACCESS. For more
>   information read about scopes.

Secondary to that I'm not sure how your request is working using query params instead of a JSON request body?  I can only get your query working using

```
{"start_latitude": 37.7752278, "start_longitude": -122.4197513, "end_latitude": 37.7773228, "end_longitude":-122.4272052}
```