# Access to partner.admin_accounts

Tags: uber-api

How we can get access to partner.admin_accounts scope ?

We catch response:

```
{"code":"unauthorized","message":"This endpoint requires all of the following scopes: partner.admin_accounts"}
```

When trying to GET

```
https://api.uber.com/v1/partners/drivers
```

upd: full code, we using GAS

```
function uberGET(){
  var token = 'my_secret_tocen';
  var url =  'https://api.uber.com/v1/partners/drivers'; 
  var header = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
               'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token};
  var options = {'method':'GET','headers':header,'muteHttpExceptions': true};
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
  Logger.log(response);
}
```

upd:
it looks like we need to get full access, but ....

...official support help.uber.com sent us here and on their Twitter :)

upd:
that "official" form:
https://developer.uber.com/products/drivers
is now working((

@Sasa Jovanovic any way for we can ask full access?

Comment: Would you please add the code you are utilising?  There may not be enough information as you have posted to answer this adequately.

Comment: See this similar question to [request authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45912281/this-endpoint-requires-at-least-one-of-the-following-scopes-profile-surge-acce).